# Each child in a list should have a unique "key" warning when every key is already unique

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can somebody tell me why I get `Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop` even after I created a unique key for every element?

I can access every key by `keys[index].tag-name` from the `keys` object array and verify that it is unique.

```
return (
    Object.entries(props.values).map(([key, value], index) => (
        <div>
            <span key={keys[index].span} />
            <p key={keys[index].p} />
        </div>
    ))
);

// key format "c98301e0-f2bd-4442-a829-407e6beecf0d"
```

Comment: You do not need keys on `span` and `p`, just a parent `div` . And plus, I  believe in that case only `keys[index]`should suffice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the key to the parent that is being returned, here `div`

```
return (
    Object.entries(props.values).map(([key, value], index) => (
        <div key={keys[index].div}>
            <span />
            <p />
        </div>
    ))
);
```

Comment: Yes, of course, I didn't though of that, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You must add key property to a parent element. In your case that's a `div`.

```
return (
    Object.entries(props.values).map(([key, value], index) => (
        <div key={keys[index].span} >
            <span/>
            <p key={keys[index].p} />
        </div>
    ))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the key into div, maybe this can solve your problem

```
return (
    Object.entries(props.values).map(([key, value], index) => (
        <div key={keys[index].span}>
            <span  />
            <p  />
        </div>
    ))
);
```